# Can we create a circular uitableview in iphone program?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-controls

Can we create a Circular/ Rounded Shape `UITableview` ?

I know that we can rounded the corners of table view or by transform we can rotate table view but is need `UITableview` to scroll in clock wise or anti-clock wise direction.

Can we use some other custom control to implement this.

Comment: i think is more easy to build a custom class that isn't a subclass of uitableview for this

Comment: you want the whole table rounded or each specific cell ?

Comment: @IronManGill I need whole table view rounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these links.. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/circleview and https://iphone2020.wordpress.com/tag/circular-tableview/. It may help you.

Comment: Not working.. means?? Didn't get you. whether the sample is not as per your requirement or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has trouble with the above links, you can get the code directly from GitHub here https://github.com/bharath2020/UITableViewTricks.  It is a drag and drop solution that you can implement and have working in your project in minutes.