# How to Make UITableview or UICollectionview in Round Shape Like Below Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

it is possible to show tableview or collectionview with scrolling images in landscape view?

as per shown in image i want to show tableview or collection view in left and right corner in round shape.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we create a circular uitableview in iphone program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418373/can-we-create-a-circular-uitableview-in-iphone-program)

Comment: Here is a custom menu some like your provided image [link1](http://www.code4app.net/ios/Path-4.2-menu-using-CoreAnimation-in-Swift/54d422cae247416035acbddd). Try to google and you would get some library for it.

Comment: i have same problem did you find any solution?

Comment: I have no exact idea but refer this link [core-graphics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/34003/core-graphics-tutorial-curves-and-layers) may be it helps.

Comment: @bhavesh did you implemented same?